# How to hide the iOS app content view when app is not active?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a cover screen to app when app is pushed to background by user.

I have these two methods on AppDelegate to add/remove the cover view.

```
func showCover(){
  let blackV = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.bounds ?? .zero)
  blackV.backgroundColor = .black
  blackV.tag = kCoverTag
  let imgV = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Logo-White"))
  imgV.center = blackV.center
  blackV.addSubview(imgV)
  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(blackV)
}

func hideCover(){
  if let blackV = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews.filter({$0.tag == kCoverTag}).first{
     blackV.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

The tag value is declared on AppDelegate:

```
 let kCoverTag = 987
```

In the `applicationWillResignActive` , I apply the cover

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    showCover()
}
```

and in didBecomeActive, I remove the cover.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
   hideCover()
}
```

This works fine when app is sent to background by pressing home button.

Right after the `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called, when I print the subviews of keyWindow , I get the output as:

```
po UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews
▿ Optional<Array<UIView>>
  ▿ some : 2 elements
    - 0 : <UITransitionView: 0x7f97bd82ffc0; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000028ecce0>>
    - 1 : <UIView: 0x7f97bae27f20; frame = (0 0; 414 896); tag = 987; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002868400>>
```

This is good as it shows the cover view as one of the subview added to the key window.

Now, when the app is sent to background by calling `UIApplication.shared.openURL` , the applicationWillResignActive is called as expected.

And when the user press the "Back to app button" , the app will be shown back to user.

Now,when I print the subviews of key window in the `didBecomeActive` method right before calling `hideCover()` method, it looks like it has only one subview.

```
po UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews
▿ Optional<Array<UIView>>
  ▿ some : 1 element
    - 0 : <UITransitionView: 0x7f97bfc05510; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000029984c0>>
```

Since this shows only one view, the `hideCover()` method couldn't find the subview and hence couldn't remove it. But in the app I could see the cover view .

I'm wondering why the `keyWindow` subviews didn't show the added cover view.

I'm testing this in simulator.

**Update:**

I did two separate print calls

Right after adding the cover view:

```
print("resign active",UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews)
```

This show two subviews for keyWindow

and right before removing the cover view in didBecomeActive method:

```
print("did become active",UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews)
```

This show only ONE subview for keyWindow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `keyWindow` here. That's not the right tool. There can be other windows created by the system and may have input focus via `makeKey()`. Present the view from the `window.rootViewController` from your `UIApplicationDelegate`. See [QA1838: Preventing Sensitive Information From Appearing In The Task Switcher](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1838/_index.html) for Apple's recommended way to implement what you're trying to do. Also see [Preparing Your UI to Run in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background) for additional guidance.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I'll go through them and update my question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to cover my app

```
  var secureView: UIView?
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
          secureView = UIView()
                secureView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  public func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.secureView?.removeFromSuperview()
  }

  public func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first, let view = secureView {
      view.frame = window.bounds
      window.addSubview(view)
    }
  }
```

for someone want to add story board:

```
override
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        showSplashScreen()
    }

    override
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        removeSplashScreen()
    }
    
    func showSplashScreen() {
        let launchScreen = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
        guard let launchScreen = launchScreen,
              let launchView = launchScreen.view else {
            return
        }
        
        launchView.tag = 8888
        launchView.frame = window.bounds
        self.window?.addSubview(launchView)
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
    func removeSplashScreen() {
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last,
              let view = window.viewWithTag(8888) else {
            return
        }
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```